# set ringtone app android

Tags: android, web, ringtone

I want to build an android app. Basically, I have a Web site where I have a lot of music into categories and from there you can listen to it or download. I want to use my app to have a mobile view of my site, and I know how to do it with android studio, there are just some things I need to change. Anyway, I want the app background/style to be different, and I want everytime I add a new category to my site, to be added to my app to. At first, I was wanting to make a button for every category, but I realised it won t work. 
Anyway, in the app,  the first thing that you ll see are the categories, then if you click on one of them, you will se a list of ringtone,  and if you click on a ringtone, you will have 4 options : set as ringtone, set as notification, set as alarm. I know what s the code for this things, what I do not understand is where to place it, because I want my app to use the music from my site, not to have a music as an asset and then set it (that s the way I know how to do it). I know is redundant, but I am a teenager:)). I know how to build an app that can set a ringtone, I do not know how to do it for hundreds of ringtones that I do not have as an asset. 
Some ideas please ? Maybe a video oor something to read

Comment: You need to show us some code if you need any help!! Just add what you already tried and comment out where you are having problem with.

Comment: And are you able two use any third party libraries or not?

Comment: I didn't write anything, I am analysing the idea because I do not not where I should start... a friend has a site with ringtones, I would want to help him make an app that have that things, like set as ringtone, as alarm tone and play the song. I know what I should write, but I do not understand how I should do it. I think it s a bad idea to make a new button for every song... and I do not know how to refer to a song that I do not have in my pc, but the song is online on my friend's site

Answer (score 0):

For playing a ringtone for preview purposes you have two options:
You can either stream it via the MediaPlayer class.
which is done like this:

```
String url = "http://your-path";
MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mPlayer.prepare();
mPlayer.start();
```

but keep in mind that prepare() method might take a while and it blocks UI thread. you need to use prepareAsync() and set a listener for it when prepared.

```
mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mPlayer.start();
        }
});
```

but if you'd also like to download it before playing it you can use this library [AQuery](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/). If you are new to android it can really help you to easily make http calls and downloads asynchronously. It is initiated and used as follows:

```
AQuery aq = new AQuery(context);
File ringtoneFileToDownload = new File("http://path/to/your/online/ringtone");
aq.download(url, ringtoneFileToDownload, new AjaxCallback<File>(){
      @Override
      public void callback(String url, File file, AjaxStatus status) {
                //method is called when the download is finished
                //and the file parameter is the file downloaded
                //which you can play as above with the MediaPlayer class
        }

});
```

you can use the above method to download it to the device and keep them local.

As the last thing don't forget to add the required permissions in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```